# How to make sure the query executed before render() on Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I don't know whether it is async problem so that sometimes the result had no product data but only type data. However, sometimes it will have both data.

My setup:
Node JS, Express, Mongoose

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
var data = {};
Product.find().limit(4).populate({path: 'region_id', model: Region})
    .then(function (doc) {
        data.product = doc;
    });
Type.find()
    .then(function (doc) {
        data.type = doc;
    });

res.render('index', {title: 'Home', items: data});
});
```

If I am correct then how to make sure all the find() function is executed before running render().

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because both asynchronous operations return `Promise`s, you should use `Promise.all`, which will resolve when both complete. There's no need for an outer `data` object, just use the values of the resolved promises directly. Also, don't forget to handle errors with `catch` when using Promises:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  Promise.all([
    Product.find().limit(4).populate({path: 'region_id', model: Region}),
    Type.find()
  ])
    .then(([product, type]) => {
      res.render('index', {title: 'Home', items: { product, type } });
    });
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle errors
    });
});
```